# Traversing methods with jquery to N level of a html table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a structure of nested table, I'm trying to get the value of a cell and paint the parentrow with the condition I give.
I can't figure it out what it is wrong in my code, I even tried prev(), or parent(), no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated!

ps. do not mind the css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.child2.2.5').each(function(index) {
    var me = $(this);
    if (me.text() == "child 2.2.5") {
      me.closest('tr.parentrow').css('background-color', 'green');
    } else if (me.text() == "child 2.2.6") {
      me.closest('tr.parentrow').css('background-color', 'red');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
td,
th {
  width: 50px;
}
table {
  width: 800px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>header 1</th>
    <th>header 2</th>
    <th>header 3</th>
    <th>header 4</th>
    <th>header 5</th>
    <th>header 6</th>
    <th>header 7</th>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="parentrow">
      <td>parent 1</td>
      <td>parent 1</td>
      <td>parent 1</td>
      <td>parent 1</td>
      <td>parent 1</td>
      <td>parent 1</td>
      <td>parent 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="childrow">
      <td colspan=7>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="child1.1">child 1.1</td>
            <td class="child1.2">child 1.2</td>
            <td class="child1.3">child 1.3</td>
            <td class="child1.4">child 1.4</td>
            <td class="child1.5">child 1.5</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="parentrow">
      <td>parent 2</td>
      <td>parent 2</td>
      <td>parent 2</td>
      <td>parent 2</td>
      <td>parent 2</td>
      <td>parent 2</td>
      <td>parent 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="childrow">
      <td colspan=7>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="child2.1.1">child 2.1.1</td>
            <td class="child2.1.2">child 2.1.2</td>
            <td class="child2.1.3">child 2.1.3</td>
            <td class="child2.1.4">child 2.1.4</td>
            <td class="child2.1.5">child 2.1.5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="child2.2.1">child 2.2.1</td>
            <td class="child2.2.2">child 2.2.2</td>
            <td class="child2.2.3">child 2.2.3</td>
            <td class="child2.2.4">child 2.2.4</td>
            <td class="child2.2.5">child 2.2.5</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do not use meta charters `.` in class name i.e. `class ="child2.2.5"`, otherwise you have to escape them with ` \\ ` like `'$(".child2\\.2\\.5")`

Comment: `$('.child2.2.5')` will select elements with the class `child2` and the class `2` and the class `5`.

Comment: something like `if(me.text() =="child 2\.2\.5"){` ? escape chars you mean? Because I tried it without dots, nothing changed

Comment: `  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.child225').each(function(index){
         var me = $(this);
         if(me.text() =="child225"){` and `<td class ="child225">child225</td>` should be ok, but I do not see it working!  thanks of course for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `.` is a meta characters, use `\\` to escape it. *I would recommend you not to use them.*

```
$('.child2\\.2\\.5')
```

[**Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  **!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^{|}~**) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.

And `parentrow` is preceding sibling of current elements parent `childrow` you have to travese using it.

```
$('.child2\\.2\\.5').each(function(index) {
    var me = $(this);
    if (me.text() == "child 2.2.5") {
      me.closest('tr.childrow').prev('.parentrow').css('background-color', 'green');
    } else if (me.text() == "child 2.2.6") {
      me.closest('tr.childrow').prev('.parentrow').css('background-color', 'red');
    }
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.child2\\.2\\.5').each(function(index) {
    var me = $(this);
    if (me.text().trim() == "child 2.2.5") {
      me.closest('tr.childrow').prev('.parentrow').css('background-color', 'green');
    } else if (me.text() == "child 2.2.6") {
      me.closest('tr.childrow').prev('.parentrow').css('background-color', 'red');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
td,
th {
  width: 50px;
}
table {
  width: 800px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>header 1</th>
    <th>header 2</th>
    <th>header 3</th>
    <th>header 4</th>
    <th>header 5</th>
    <th>header 6</th>
    <th>header 7</th>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="parentrow">
      <td>parent 1</td>
      <td>parent 1</td>
      <td>parent 1</td>
      <td>parent 1</td>
      <td>parent 1</td>
      <td>parent 1</td>
      <td>parent 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="childrow">
      <td colspan=7>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="child1.1">child 1.1</td>
            <td class="child1.2">child 1.2</td>
            <td class="child1.3">child 1.3</td>
            <td class="child1.4">child 1.4</td>
            <td class="child1.5">child 1.5</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="parentrow">
      <td>parent 2</td>
      <td>parent 2</td>
      <td>parent 2</td>
      <td>parent 2</td>
      <td>parent 2</td>
      <td>parent 2</td>
      <td>parent 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="childrow">
      <td colspan=7>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="child2.1.1">child 2.1.1</td>
            <td class="child2.1.2">child 2.1.2</td>
            <td class="child2.1.3">child 2.1.3</td>
            <td class="child2.1.4">child 2.1.4</td>
            <td class="child2.1.5">child 2.1.5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="child2.2.1">child 2.2.1</td>
            <td class="child2.2.2">child 2.2.2</td>
            <td class="child2.2.3">child 2.2.3</td>
            <td class="child2.2.4">child 2.2.4</td>
            <td class="child2.2.5">child 2.2.5</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```